# Removing text from Foreach iteration

Tags: php

Currently, I have the following code.

```
foreach($html->find('ol.tracklist li.track') as $element) {
   print $element->plaintext;
   print '<br>';
}
```

Which returns something that looks like this.

```
Can't Use My Phone (Suite) 3:34
Hi 0:35
Cel U Lar Device 6:28
Phone Down 3:29
U Use To Call Me 1:13
Mr. Telephone Man 3:12
```

I am wondering how I can remove the numbers at each of these results. I am assuming I have to use regex to achieve this, but after messing with regex a bit, I was unable to find a way to achieve this without affecting the titles that also contain things like. `:` or other symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), using a regex to match the pattern you have at the end, and replace that with an empty string:

```
print preg_replace('/\d+:\d+\s*$/`, '', $element->plaintext);
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c5k9Oy/1)

[PHP Demo](https://3v4l.org/tr3Le)

Answer (score 3):

try this one it may help you, change `$str` variable with your text

```
$re = '/\d+:\d+/m';
$str = 'Caint Use My Phone (Suite) 3:34';

echo preg_replace($re, '', $str);
```

Comment: Beautiful answer, this would have solved my problem as well so I've voted up your answer. However, I saw Nick's post before hand. Thank you so much for taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 2):

You should try this regex `/\d+:\d+$/gm`.

- \d+ will match 1 digit or more.
- : will match literal char of ':'.
- $ will search the above pattern at the end of the line.
- g will continue to search for each line on each line (w/o it you will return 
   after the first match)
- m will enable multi line search, which mean that the search will refer the $ 
   at the end of each line (w/o it it will search at the end of the text only)

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

You can just cut the last character of each string as long as it is either a number or a colon:

```
foreach($html->find('ol.tracklist li.track') as $element) {
    $text = $element->plaintext;

    while(preg_match('/[\d:]$/', $text[strlen($text)-1])) {
        $text = substr($text, 0, strlen($text)-1);
    }

    echo $text;
    print '<br>';
}
```

[PHP DEMO](https://3v4l.org/HX82i)

Answer (score 1):

If it's always the same format hh:mm you can find the last space with strrpos()

```
$string = 'Cel U Lar Device 6:28';
$string = substr($string, 0, strrpos($string, ' '));
```

Answer (score -2):

Probably not the best solution but, you could just cut off the last 4-5 characters in the string

```
substr( $string, 0, -5 );
```

Comment: This would be a horrible idea, because sometimes the numbers don't appear in the iteration at all. Hence me needing to use Regex as mentioned.